# Changed URL of a site, now Google won't index it

Tags: google, google-search-console, html, typo3

So within typo3 I changed the URL of site so it fits better with the content of the site.

Then I got Search Console to crawl. Now it says that Google won't index the site because the canonical link that Google found is different from the one I put in.

Did I did something wrong in typo3? How will Google find the new site?

I tried to change canonical link. But it doesn't not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the URL"?  Are you moving to a new domain?  Are you updating the URL path?  Both?

Comment: It is very hard to help you without more details.  Can you share more details?  It would be helpful to see the code you are using for canonicals or screenshots from Google Search Console.

Comment: Im using typo3 for setting the canonicals. No new domain. Just a new/changed url.

Comment: What is the code you are using in typo3 for canonicals?

Comment: rel=”canonical”

Comment: Yes but where is that tag going within the page? Was the contents of the canonical?

Comment: Please show more contents of your html page that contains the internal link.  You can replace the url to use example.com

Comment: <link rel="canonical" href="example.com"/>